# Unable to route to external http proxy when using a kubernetes service for DNS resolution of proxy addresses

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, istio

I have use case where we want to route certain requests via a corporate HTTP proxy. Based on [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/http-proxy/#configure-traffic-to-external-https-proxy) guide I was able to configure the external access successfully. For context I've added a example ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: proxy
spec:
  addresses:
    - 10.1.1.1
    - 10.1.1.2
  exportTo:
  - .
  hosts:
  - foo.proxy # this is technically ignored when protocol is TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    number: 3128
    protocol: TCP
```

This works when we have the app automatically resolve to one of the proxy addresses above (i.e: host file entry).

In an effort to provide automatic DNS resolution I setup a a k8s [Service without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) as per the docs. In a **non istio** namespace, this allows me to resolve `foo.proxy.default.cluster.local` without the host file entries as expected e.g:

```
curl -v --proxy foo.default.svc.cluster.local:3128 https://blah.com
```

However within a istio namespace with the existing ServiceEntry (above) it fails with a `404 Not Found`. The logs show:

```
2021-08-11T08:56:47.088919Z debug   envoy router    [C1114][S1115555414526221653] no cluster match for URL ''
2021-08-11T08:56:47.088928Z debug   envoy http  [C1114][S1115555414526221653] Sending local reply with details route_not_found
```

Can I get some pointers on where this might be going wrong?

Comment: Which istio version did you use and how did you deploy the cluster? This is most likely caused when a request is sent to a virtual service that does not match the criteria defined by any of the routes defined under a virtual router provider. Make sure that the requests from the application are sent to a supported route by ensuring the path and HTTP request headers are correct.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak version 1.9. I haven't defined Virtual Services. Besides the Service Entry this namespace has no other istio configurations applied.

Comment: How did you set up your cluster? Did you use some cloud providor (which?)

Comment: Amazon EKS. So how does this impact istio..?

Comment: Cloud providor information may be needed to replicate the problem. Your error is that envoy router cannot see any url that the cluster is in. He doesn't know where to hit because he doesn't have an address. Try changing the hostname to the fully qualified domain name. This can be because you are using different namespaces. Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error the solution to make this work is as following:

1. K8s Service must have a named port

For example, I had:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
```

But it must include the `spec.ports.[].name`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: tcp # critial. alternatively prefix any name with protocol-<name>
      port: 8080
```

This is documented at:
https://istio.io/v1.9/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/

For completeness here's the k8s Endpoints example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: foo
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.1.1.1
      - ip: 10.1.1.2
    ports:
      - port: 8080
```

The Endpoints `metadata.name` and Service `metadata.name` MUST match.

Now to the more interesting part.

1. Create a Service Entry for the VIP.

I replaced my original ServiceEntry with the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: foo-forward-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - foo.default.svc.cluster.local
  addresses:
  - 172.20.254.32 # my foo service ClusterIP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 8080
    name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 10.1.1.1
  - address: 10.1.1.2
```

This declares the k8s Service IP `172.20.254.32` as a VIP with the name `foo.default.svc.cluster.local` which happens to be the Service name. All traffic destined to the VIP on port 8080 will be forwarded to the endpoints.